Why Do AR-NN Models Have Tighter Confidence Intervals Compared to Linear AR Models?
I have conducted a forecast for the following data series using different autoregressive models: Intercept-only, AR1, AR2, ARIMA BIC, ARIMA AIC, and AR-NN. Using the point forecasts, the AR1 model is optimal for forecast horizons 1 and 2, while ARIMA BIC is optimal for horizons 3 and 4 based on their RMSEs which were calculated on a 70/30 training/testing split. However, when examining the central 95% prediction intervals, which were calculated by bootstrapping, the linear AR models produce very wide and uninformative PIs (second picture), whereas the PIs of the AR-NN model (first picture) are much tighter and seem more meaningful.
Is there any technical reason for this? Could it be that the non-parametric approach, even though it doesn't improve the point forecasts, is better at depicting uncertainty and therefore performs better in modeling the uncertainty?
Thank you for your insights!



The AR-NN models are almost certainly over-fitting. Look at the actual coverage compared to the nominal coverage.

@RobHyndman That is true, the actual coverage is only about 50% which is not great.
